# Alpine email client with two-factor authentication to Microsoft-hosted email service

Tags: email, oauth-2.0, smtp, two-factor-authentication

I use Alpine as an email client, running on Ubuntu OS. My employer, who uses Microsoft for its email service, has just started requiring two-factor authentication (2FA) to send email.
I cannot send email anymore.
I have followed their instructions  (https://mcgill.service-now.com/itportal?id=kb_article&sysparm_article=KB0011664) to set up the Authy app on my desktop. So it now has me authenticated to Skynet, err,  Microsoft's servers.
Is there any way I can now continue to use Alpine? I suspect the answer would be for some way to get (a plugin in) Alpine to talk to this Authy app.

Currently/previously my setup has `SMTPSERVER=smtp.office365.com:587/tls/user=my.name@mcgill.ca`
which no longer works; Alpine prompts me for a password but it fails.

Update:
I tried appending `/submit/auth=xoauth2` to the SMTP string, as described at http://alpine.x10host.com/alpine/alpine-info/misc/SettingXOAUTH2Outlook.html , but this did not have the behaviour described on that page. Instead, when I try to send Alpine says:

```
  [>Error sending: Client does not support AUTH=xoauth2 authenticator<]
```

Comment: I have the very same problem (just different domain/company). Current apline from git (2.26+), debug log contains following:
`IMAP DEBUG 11:30:27.400416: * CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=NTLM AUTH=GSSAPI SASL-IR UIDPLUS MOVE ID UNSELECT CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+`, no XOAUTH2 indeed

Answer (score 0):

I have good news for those of us tied to open standards and open source software. The 2 factor authentication that you have setup through the Authy app is based on [rfc6238](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6238). The secret that you save in Authy app in the following step of the setup is all you need to generate the 2FA code:

[image]

The benefit of the Authy app is that you can use it to store the secret, generate your 2FA code and encrypt and back up the secret so that it becomes harder to lose. While your IT documentation recommends Authy as the only other application they will try to support, you could choose to use any open source authenticator application that implements rfc6238.

The other side of the coin is that your mail client, Alpine, will need to be able to handle 2FA requests from your mail server. I know nothing about building Linux mail clients, but it seems it's possible as [Evolution, with the evolution-ews plugin, supports 2FA with Office365](http://galileo.phys.virginia.edu/compfac/faq/evolution-office365-mfa.html). You might need to take this up with the Alpine maintainers though.

Comment: Thanks. Agreed there are many (e.g. command line) alternatives to authy. What I want is for Alpine to use it/them, or for some shell syntax to use in Alpine's SMTP field, or etc. I submitted this: https://github.com/realpine/alpine/issues/32

Comment: The Realpine repo is not the maintained one. You want to go here instead:
https://alpine.x10host.com/alpine/
On the left is a link "XOAUTH2" which will take you to:
https://alpine.x10host.com/alpine/alpine-info/misc/SettingXOAUTH2Outlook.html
which I think is what you need.